How to Reverse the Order of Points in a Forest Plot in ggplot2
I'm creating a forest plot using ggplot2 in R, and I'm having trouble with the order of points. I want to plot two groups ("Group A" and "Group B") and within each group, I want to show two categories ("Category 1" and "Category 2"). However, I need to ensure that "Category 1" is plotted above "Category 2" for each group. So the grey line should be above the black line. But the legend should stay as it is.
I've tried changing the order of factors and using the reverse argument in guides, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired order.
Here's my current code:
# Load necessary packages
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Create data
data <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(c('Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B'),
                 levels = c('Group A', 'Group B')),
  Category = factor(c('Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 1', 'Category 2'),
                    levels = c('Category 1', 'Category 2')),
  OR = c(1.2, 1.5, 1.1, 1.3),
  CI_Lower = c(0.9, 1.2, 0.8, 1.0),
  CI_Upper = c(1.6, 1.8, 1.4, 1.6)
)

# Colors and shapes for categories
colors <- c('#A9A9A9', 'black')
shapes <- c(24, 19)

# Set window font
windowsFonts(A = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))

# Create plot
forest_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = OR, y = Group, color = Category, shape = Category)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), aes(fill = Category)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = CI_Lower, xmax = CI_Upper, color = Category), height = 0, size = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +
  labs(x = "Odds Ratio", y = "") +
  xlim(0.5, 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(OR == 1.5, paste0(OR, "***"), OR)), vjust = -0.5, hjust = 1.5, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), family = "A", show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "A") +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12, family = "A"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12, family = "A"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10, family = "A"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, family = "A"),
        legend.position = c(0.99, 0.99),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), "cm")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Group A\nCategory", "Group B\nCategory")) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))

print(forest_plot)


The order by which your points and error bars get dodged is determined by the group aes which in your case defaults to Category. Hence, to reverse the order convert Category to a factor with reversed levels and map this factor on the group aes only. This way neither the mapping on color and/or shape nor the legend is affected:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(
  x = OR, y = Group,
  color = Category, shape = Category,
  group = factor(Category, levels = rev(paste("Category", 1:2)))
)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), aes(fill = Category)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = CI_Lower, xmax = CI_Upper, color = Category), height = 0, size = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +
  labs(x = "Odds Ratio", y = "") +
  xlim(0.5, 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(OR == 1.5, paste0(OR, "***"), OR)),
    vjust = -0.5, hjust = 1.5, size = 5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.position = c(0.99, 0.99),
    legend.justification = c(1, 1),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), "cm")
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Group A\nCategory", "Group B\nCategory")) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: A numeric `legend.position` argument in `theme()` was deprecated in ggplot2
#> 3.5.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `legend.position.inside` argument of `theme()` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.1.0
